# What are the disadvantages of chainloading windows?

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi

So I want to dual boot windows 10 and another linux distro (probably going to end up being manjaro), and I've seen everyone say to just chainload windows. I was wondering if there were any disadvantages to chainloading windows especally when I'm running in UEFI exclusive mode.

Answer (score 2):

Well, their's not a direct performance cost except maybe an extra few seconds during boot while the grub2 gives you a chance to select which OS to boot. And you don't lose any features of either OS. If I had to pick a downside it would be that if something goes wrong with your bootloader under *nix you lose access to both Windows and *nix at the same time.

That said, if you have UEFI there's no real need to chain load. Just install both OSes in EFI mode. Windows and Ubuntu both do this automatically if you use EFI to boot the install cd... but dunno about manjaro. That should result in you having two different boot items listed in your UEFI boot order in your BIOS, one for Windows and one for *nix. You can then just use your BIOS's boot selection feature to choose which OS to launch. Such is not generally as feature rich as grub2 would be, but it also doesn't give you an additional single point of failure like grub2 does.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "chainload" generally means one boot program launching another one. In the case of a Windows/Linux dual-boot, this is usually GRUB 2 launching the Windows boot loader, although there are other ways to do this, including both non-GRUB boot loaders and the Windows boot manager launching GRUB rather than the other way around. The boot path to boot Windows does not normally involve a Linux kernel, just one extra boot loader.

As a general rule, launching the Windows boot loader from GRUB 2 causes no harm or problems, aside from slightly increasing the Windows boot time. Depending on your preferences, this increase can be quite small. For instance, you could set the default boot manager to boot Windows by default with a short timeout period, which would result in a small increase in the time to boot Windows vs. having a Windows-only boot. There is another issue, though -- see below.

On rare occasion, one boot manager causes complications when launching another. For instance, [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464) renders Windows unbootable from GRUB 2 if Secure Boot is enabled. I've heard of other, more exotic problems, involving specific hardware devices that fail when a new boot manager is inserted into the boot sequence. Such problems are rare, though.

In a dual boot between Windows 8 or later and anything else, though, the biggest complication is likely to be the Windows Fast Startup and Hibernate features. These features, which are active by default, turn a shutdown operation into a suspend-to-disk operation. This has the benefit of reducing startup time the next time you start the computer. The dual-boot drawback is that if you boot your other OS, the partitions used by Windows will appear to be in an inconsistent state, which can prevent shared partitions from being used; and if the non-Windows OS tries to repair them, Windows will become confused the next time you boot it. The result can be disk corruption and weird effects like boot loaders malfunctioning. (On EFI, boot loaders are stored on a shared FAT partition that can suffer from this problem.) Thus, it's imperative that you disable both Fast Startup and Hibernate, as described [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here,](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) respectively, for Windows 10. Doing so will increase the Windows boot time. This problem really has nothing to do with chainloading per se, though; it's a complication of Microsoft's using suspend-to-disk instead of a full shutdown in recent versions of Windows.